# When we use http.createServer() in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I just started learning Node.js, and I'm wondering when developer should/need to use `http.createServer()`

My process of thinking is: "When I want to catch data from server I use: `http.request` and `http.get` methodes.

When I want to POST on server I will use `http.request` with POST method options parameter.

I just can’t figure out, when I should use `http.createServer()` method?

If I work on remote server (server is already exists).

I red documentation: `This class is used to create a TCP or IPC server.`

w3School says: `The http.createServer() method turns your computer into an HTTP server.`

If you can, give me comprehensive explanation with real world example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use something like `http.request()`, you're connecting to another HTTP server and requesting data from it.  If you wanted to be that server yourself, you would need to use `http.createServer()` to do that.

For example, a common use case of Node.js is to create an API server that receives HTTP requests from web pages and fetches or manipulates data in a database.  It takes the resulting data and sends it as an HTTP response.

The Node.js documentation you read seems to be for `net.createServer()`.  While `http.createServer()` does create an underlying TCP server, it also accepts a callback for listening for HTTP requests.

See also:  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener

Comment: If I understand correctly: "When I want to be able to handle requests on server side, I need to have `http.createServer()` on my server to make it possible." 


Example: 
MyServer: `http.crateServer()`
ClientSide: `fetch('http://....)` ---> this request is possible to handle  on server side because of this ---> http.createServer()

Comment: thanks a bunch!

Can I ask you one more question, here in thred. It is only partly connected with this one.

Comment: @PredragDavidovic You should post a new separate question.  Others in the future will have similar questions as you, and keeping each question separate helps people find the information.

Comment: I would like to post another question, but this my question and 2 more are downvoted, and Stackoverflow blocked possibility to ask question for me. :(

Comment: @PredragDavidovic I just upvoted one of your questions here... try it now.

Comment: Hi man, thanks a lot. I can ask questions again. I have to be careful about how to post it. 
Thanks a lot ;)